# Next.js errors when building dynamically routed pages that use Apollo useQuery and its skip parameter

Tags: react-hooks, next.js, apollo, apollo-client, react-apollo

I have two somewhat different but related problems when trying to build my Next.js app. Specifically, the error occurs at "Generating static pages" stage of the build (everything runs fine with `npm run dev`). Here is the first problematic bit of code:

```js
export const Address: NextPage = () => {
  const router = useRouter();
  const { address_bech32 } = router.query as {
    address_bech32: string;
  };

  const current_epoch = getCurrentEpoch();
  
  // useAddressQuery is a function generated by graphql-let (https://github.com/piglovesyou/graphql-let)
  // Pretty sure it is just a type-safe wrapper around Apollo's `useQuery`
  const { data, loading, error } = useAddressQuery({
    variables: {
      address_bech32,
      current_epoch,
    },
    skip: !router.isReady, // <- without this line page builds fine
  });
  ...
```

I receive the following error:

```bash
Error occurred prerendering page "/address/[address_bech32]". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error
undefined
```

The `skip` parameter is important as it prevents Apollo from sending two queries, the first of which will have `address_bech32` being undefined. However, I've determined that this line is the source of the build error. Why is Next throwing an error when generating the static pages and how should I properly implement this functionality?

The second error is very similar and might be resolved by the solution to the first but just in case here is the code:

```js
export const Search: NextPage = () => {
  const router = useRouter();
  let { query } = router.query as {
    query: string;
  };

  const { data, error, loading } = useSearchQuery({
    variables: { 
      query_int: query.match(/^-?\d+$/) ? parseInt(query, 10) : -1, 
      query_bytea: query.match(/[0-9A-Fa-f]{6}/g) ? "\\x" + query : "\\x", 
      query_string: query
    },
    skip: !router.isReady,
  });
  ...
```

Here is the build error I get:

```bash
Error occurred prerendering page "/search". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error
TypeError: Cannot read property 'match' of undefined
```

Ok so obviously at build time `query` is undefined because there is just no data. In this case the error is thrown regardless of whether `skip` is included or not. Again, what's the proper way to implement this kind of functionality?

Please let me know if I should include any additional info! Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a work around by disabling static generation for the page using the nextjs [getInitialProps](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/automatic-static-optimization) method:

```js
PageComponent.getInitialProps = async () => {
  return {}
}
```

Definitely a hacky solution but it let me build the site.